# Condition equivalent to: Set is homeomorphic to closed subspace of Euclidean space

Tags: general-topology

I was reading a paper, in which the author stated the following side remark:

> "[... these spaces are precisely] the locally compact, finite dimensional separable metrizable spaces, or equivalently, those spaces homeomorphic to a closed subspace of Euclidean space.''

By "finite dimensional", they mean the Lebesgue covering dimension, which is a topological invariant.

I am trying to understand why this is true.
One direction is clear to me: A set which is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of Euclidean space is locally compact, finite dimensional, separable and metrizable.
But why is the converse true?

**(Why) is every the locally compact, finite dimensional, separable, metrizable topological space homeomorphic to a closed subspace of Euclidean space?**

---

My best attempt so far is to use Uryssohn's Imbedding Theorem:

> If $X$ is a second countable normal space, then there exists a homeomorphism $f$ of $X$ onto a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, and therefore $X$ is metrizable.

Since the space is metrizable, it is normal.
Since it is metrizable, separable is equivalent to second countable.
So, it follows that the space described in my question is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$.
I suppose then one can deduce it is homeomorphic to a subspace of a (finite-dimensional) Euclidean space, since the space itself is finite-dimensional.

Assuming that my reasoning up to here is correct, I'm left with one question:
Why does it follow that there exists such a Euclidean subspace, which is *closed*?

Comment: Every separable metric space of dimension $\leq n$ embeds into $\Bbb R^{2n+1}$

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti but not as a closed one, unless we hapen to have a compact  space...?

Answer (score 3):

There is a universal space embedding theorem which tells us that a separable metrisable space $X$ with $\dim(X) =n $ embeds into $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ (in fact a subspace of it, Nöbeling universal space (see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension) e.g.).

When $X$ is locally compact for any embedding $i: X \to \Bbb R^N$ we have that $i[X] = O \cap C$ where $O$ is open and $C$ is closed; a standard fact for locally compact spaces.

OTOH, being homeomorphic to a closed subset of a power of $\Bbb R$ is a well-known topological property, called [realcompactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realcompact_space). And all separable metric spaces are realcompact (being Lindelöf $T_3$), but the power we need to achive closedness could well be infinite.

So both routes do not yet give us a closed embedding into a finite power.

I'll look a bit further in the literature for related theorems.

Comment: No luck so far finding a good theorem